# How can I find element by "aria-label" attribute name in Watin?

Tags: html, watin, wai-aria

How can I find element by `aria-label` attribute name in Watin?

I searched all the options but didn't find any way to do it.

Comment: You should be able to use `ie.TextField("name:txt_FirstName").TypeText` but it's hard to advise further without additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Find.By("aria-label","value") constraint.

Thanks,

Sham_